# creating a robot from ez-b or regular arduino

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

Does anyone have experience with this **ez-b**, it is sold by *ez-robot.com* and comes with an SDK for Visual Studio

It has direct scripting in runtime and through usb or bluetooth, wifi, irc, https

My question is, if I get a regular arduino board, will i be able to do the same?
from what ive read, arduino needs to hold the instructions on its own memory, but I rather have the brain in the computer, and feed signals back and forth to the microcontroller

Also, is **arduino** alone, a step down as the website niceley puts it

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: If you are going to do offboard processing, you will need a reliable wired or radio (or similar) link.  Most of the non-ATMEGEA Arduino-format boards have more on-chip resources, but may not be as widely and openly supported.

Comment: I want to use my computer as the brain. Its 8core win 7,8tb mem, 8gig ram and sits around in silence collecting dust as it watches its soulmate stolen by a younger, sleeker laptop

Comment: much less people browsing that topic, but i've added it there. perhaps you can kee this open so that someone who knows the answer and doesnt venture to robotics can answer this question